# ICollection.ToList().Insert doesn't insert value

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have for example a **Tree**, which has an **ICollection** of **nodes**:

```
public class Tree
{
    public ICollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I try to do:

```
_tree.Nodes.ToList().Insert(position, newNode);
```

I get no exception, but it *doesn't* insert the value.

When I make Nodes a List, it works fine.

Why does **ICollection.ToList().Insert()** not work?

Comment: Any time a method doesn't do what you think it should the first thing you should do is [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netcore-3.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToList__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__).

Comment: It seems more logical to simply change the reference value from ICollection to a list rather than to a convert a list every time and creating new List() @Va Co

Comment: Inserting a node into a list of nodes in a tree by index seems odd since you generally insert a node as a child/sibling to an existing node in a tree.

Comment: @DourHighArch fair enough I didn't mention that I've already googled/checked documentation. But how does this documentation answer my question in any way?

Comment: @Batuhan as I said in my original post, I've done that, I want to find out why my first attempt doesn't work.

Comment: @devNull you're totally right, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4):

[`ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-5.0) creates a **new instance** of `List<T>` which is nowhere declared in your code. That's why the Insert has no visible effect. You have to reference the list that is returned from `ToList` in a variable and use that. For example:

```
var nodeList = _tree.Nodes.ToList();
nodeList.Insert(position, newNode);
_tree.Nodes = nodeList;
```

Maybe it was better to declare the collection as `List<T>` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that ToList() creates a new instance of List<Node>, and it does so with the initial 6 nodes I'm testing with. But what I don't understand is why the insert doesn't work in the new list? I'm obviously missing some key piece of knowledge, that's what I'm trying to find.

Comment: @VaCo: It works, but not on the original `Nodes` property which was just used to feed the `ToList` method, but it's used on the list that is generated in `ToList` and nowhere referenced in your code(so it's actually a no-op, just wasted cpu cycles). If you want to see the added item you need to use my code or change your property to `List<Node>` and insert it directly there.

Answer (score 1):

`ToList()` **makes a copy** of the references in the collection in a **brand new `List<Node>` object**, which the code immediately forgets. It's not just a cast.

You can assign the new list back to the variable, but I'd argue a cast may be more appropriate (and faster):

```
((List<Node>)_tree.Nodes).Insert(position, newNode);
```

If this works without causing runtime exceptions, and it really necessary (Is it? Really?), you may also want to change the definition from `ICollection<Node>` to `IList<Node>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Joel. So ToList() will just convert to a list, but won't store the values of the list anywhere?

Comment: As for the 2nd suggestion, yes I've done that, I was just trying to understand better why the first idea didn't work.

Comment: @VaCo `ToList()` does **not** convert to a list, in the sense that convert implies changing the original item. The original item does not change. As far as storing the values anywhere, `ToList()` is a function. It returns a result. It's up to you to do something with that result. The string functions all work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already by other answers, when you call .ToList() it creates a new List. Therefore it does not work.

You could also do 2 other things to solve your problem.

1: Create a method to add Node. So you don't need to call the ToList():

```
public class Tree
{
    public ICollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    public void AddNode(Node n)
    {
       if(Nodes == null)
            Nodes = new List<Node>();
        Nodes.Add(n);
    }
}
```

2. Change your collection from ICollection to List initializing its value such as:

   ```
   public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; } = new List<Node>();
   ```

Then you can just:

```
var t = new Tree(); 
t.Nodes.Add(new Node());
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I know the changing to List<Node> works, I'm asking why the  ICollection.ToList().Insert() doesn't work.

Comment: It's because you're creating a new List and adding  the value to it. Its the same as if you create a variable, lets say: int a = 10; then lather you do: a + 5; if you print a it will still be 10. Instead you should do a = a + 5;   To make your example work you will need to t.Nodes = t.Nodes.ToList().Add(....)