# How to remove an item from Expression<Func<T, object>>?

Tags: c#

I have this argument from a function

```
params Expression<Func<Customer, object>>[] includes
```

I want to check if a property is defined in one of the includes and remove it.
Something like this:

```
includes.ToList().Remove(x => x.Addresses)
```

Comment: What’s the issue?

Comment: If you just want to check if two expressions are equal, you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24528357/2791540).

Comment: @viveknuna, I simply wanted to remove an item from the includes. But the above examples doesn't work..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ICollection.ToList().Insert doesn't insert value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65795700/icollection-tolist-insert-doesnt-insert-value) Basically, `ToList` is creating a new list, you'd need to instead create a new array without that value, and assign it to `includes`

Comment: @h3n have you tried setting Addresses as  null?

Comment: Note also that `x => x.Addresses` might not be the same as what was passed in. You may need something like `includes = includes.Where(e => e != new Expression<Func<Customer, object>>(x => x.Addresses)).ToArray();`

Comment: You can do `((MemberExpression)include.Body).Member.Name == "Addresses"` (some checks that expression is indeed simple `MemberExpression` won't hurt of course).